# What's the maximum number of components in a spanning forest?

Tags: graph-theory

My course notes contain a proposition,

> Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph on $n$ vertices, and let $H=(V,S)$ be a spanning forest. Then $0\leq|S|\leq n-1$.

Shouldn't the upper bound be $|S|\leq n$? For instance, let $G=H=K_1$; then $|S|=1=n$.

Comment: It depends on whether or not you allow self-loops in a spanning forest. Typically these are not allowed because a spanning forest is a union of trees, and trees by definition do not allow loops. It is probably the case that $K_1$ is not considered a spanning forest of itself.

Comment: @MattWerenski If $K_1$ is not a spanning forest, I would expect $K_0$ not to be a spanning forest either. But then why would the lower bound be $0\leq|S|$?

Comment: Look carefully at the notation and think about what sort of elements the set $S$ has :)

Comment: If $H=(V,S)$ then $S$ is the set of edges in the graph $H$, not  the set of components. The graph $K_1$ has one component, no edges.

Comment: Thanks both @MishaLavrov and user14111. The comments are enough for me, but if either of you would like to post an answer I'll be happy to accept.